# trouble with making element sticky when scroll reaches a certain point

Tags: jquery, css, offset, sticky

I'm having trouble with what should be a simple matter. I have a particular div, and when it scrolls up to a certain point, I want to make it sticky (fixed). But it's not working. My conditions for making it sticky never seem to get met. In fact, the offset I'm tracking doesn't seem to change no matter how much I scroll. Can anyone advise, please?

html:

```
<navbar>
        <a href="http://www.post-gazette.com/"><pglogo>&nbsp;</pglogo></a>

        <textbranding>title</textbranding>

        <social>
            <a class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank" href=""></a>
            <a class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank" href=""></a>
        </social>
    </navbar>

    <section class="module parallax parallax-1">

      <h2>Title</h2>
         <h3>teaser</h3>

    </section>


  <wrapper>
<div id="chapters" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="linkChapter">main story</div> <div class="linkChapter">chapter 2</div> <div class="linkChapter">chapter 3</div><div class="linkChapter">chapter 4</div> <div class="linkChapter">chapter 5</div>
</div>

    <section id="story-start" class="row medium-9 large-7 columns storyMain">

    (lots of text)
</section>
    </wrapper>
```

jquery:

```
var $window = $(window),
       $stickyEl = $('wrapper'),
       elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
       offset = elTop - $( document ).scrollTop();
       //elTop - $(window).scrollTop()
        console.log(elTop);

   $window.scroll(function() {
       console.log(elTop-$(window).offset().top);
        if (elTop <= 40) {
            $('#chapters').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('#chapters').removeClass('sticky');
        }

        //$stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', elTop <= 40);
    });
```

css

```
navbar {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
wrapper {
    transition: background 2.0s ease;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

wrapper p {
    transition: all 2.0s ease;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 1200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/main/myimage.jpg");
  position: relative;
}
#chapters {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: -30px;
}
 #chapters.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50px;
  }
.linkChapter {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.linkChapter:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made it simple and uploaded it in codepen. This will solve your issue. I have also made minor changes in the CSS but you can ignore them and concentrate on the jquery part of it.

codepen: https://codepen.io/vikrant-icd/pen/GEQdxZ

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var elTop = $("wrapper").position(),
    window = $("body").scrollTop(),
    wrapTop = elTop.top - 80;

  if (window >= wrapTop) {
    $("#chapters").addClass("sticky");
    console.log("sticky");
  } else {
    $("#chapters").removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up having to do was putting the code on my index page -- not the ideal situation. But the code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

                    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1150) {
                            $('#chapters').addClass('sticky');

                        } else {
                            $('#chapters').removeClass('sticky');
                        }
                    }


         });
    });
```